# Send unprovoked messages using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

Is there a way to send messages to channels without being provoked? For example every few hours a skype chatbot might remind you to call your mom.

I'm using Microsoft's new [Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) and the NodeJS sdk.

Comment: This could be as simple task within your app.js file. you can iterate within function using unix timestamp with regular intervals to create message session.

You need to use the SendMessage call as you won't be replying to an existing message.

http://docs.botframework.com/connector/new-conversations/#navtitle

Answer (score 0):

Yes... All of the built in Bot classes have a `beginDialog()` method which can be used to initiate a bot originated conversation with the user. The basics-naturalLanguage example shows a sample of this using the TextBot class and there's also the testBot example which shows this in action for all of the bots. For the TestBot you have to look at the 'dialogs/run-async.js' file to see the actual call.